# Tetrads and frame fields in different topologies, regarding their bijectiveness

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, group-theory

In utilizing the standard tetrad formalism of GR one can choose orthonormal tetrad basis (frame fields) such as the “standard” ones such that:

$$g_{\mu\nu}=e_{\,\mu}^{a}\eta_{ab}e_{\,\nu}^{b}$$

and their inverses:

$$\eta_{ab}=e_{\,a}^{\mu}g_{\mu\nu}e_{\,b}^{\nu}$$

Where Greek and Latin indices indicate coordinate and non-coordinate basis respectively (business as usual). The tetrads then define a set of locally Minkowskian basis (though their Lie bracket will in general be non-vanishing). This naturally includes both the basis vectors and their accompanying dual 1-forms.

$$e_{a}=e_{\,a}^{\mu}e_{\mu}=e_{\,a}^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}$$ $$e^{a}=e_{\,\mu}^{a}e^{\mu}=e_{\,\mu}^{a}dx^{\mu}$$

In my current project it is absolutely crucial that the maps defined by $e_{\,\mu}^{a} and e_{\,a}^{\mu}$ are one-to-one and onto (a bijective mapping as it were), indeed one would expect this is a required property of the verbein already since we have that $e_{\,\mu}^{a}e_{\,a}^{\mu}=e_{\,a}^{\mu}e_{\,\mu}^{a}=Id$    (it has an inverse that can be composed from the left or the right).

And this is where I'm running into trouble, as I am working with compact spacetimes. For a simple example let use three dimensions (just to illustrate my issue) and say I'm considering spaces homeomorphic to $S^{3}$. Let us denote the metric of a unit 3-sphere $\mathscr{\mathbb{S}}_{\mu\nu}$, Euclidean three-space $\eta_{ab}$ and the metric of some space homeomorphic to $S^{3}$ as $g_{\alpha\beta}$.

And this is where my get a sour taste in my mouth, there is NO bijective mapping between $g_{\alpha\beta}$, or $\mathbb{S}_{\mu\nu}$ and $\eta_{ab}$. You can't map $S^{3}$ to $\mathbb{R^{\mathrm{3}}}$ and back in a one-to-one and onto way. Now we can hand wave and talk about adding a point at infinity to $\mathbb{R^{\mathrm{3}}}$ or subtracting a point from $S^{3}$ to make them match; however, this changes the topological properties geometry of our spaces (which doesn't seem satisfactory on physical grounds. Furthermore, as $S^{3}$ is parellizable (as are the spacetime manifolds I'm considering) we know it admits a GLOBAL set of tetrad fields, so we needen't speak of excluding points.

This suggests to me that perhaps I've clung to Minkowski space for too long and that a tetrad relation such as:

$$g_{\alpha\beta}=e_{\,\alpha}^{\mu}\mathbb{S}_{\mu\nu}e_{\,\beta}^{\nu}$$ makes much more sense for spaces that are topologically $S^{3}$. One is taking the tetrads to be bijective mappings from the unit three sphere to some other space with the same topology (though physically different).

In this sense, my first equation, the standard tetrad makes the most sense for metrics that are topologically Minkowskian, while other topologies might benefit from utilizing tetrads acting upon a simple homogenous isotropic version of that topology. That is the first part of my question, is this a valid setup for this particular case?

Please note, I understand that the compactification by adding a point at infinity to $\mathbb{R^{\mathrm{3}}}$ is equivalent in a sense; however this slight of hand obscures some of our physics. For example suppose we wish to find our spin connection for 3d system above. For tetrads mapping to $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ we have an $SO(3)$ valued connection (and a corresponding $SO(3,1)$ valued connection in the full Minkowskian case). 
Now however, considering the spin connection of the mapping to $S^{3}$ we would have an $SO(4)$ valued spin connection (as each connection is valued in the isometry group at the identity of that manifold). Note the translations of the two different methods would also be entirely different ($T^{3}$in the former and $SU(2)$ in the latter).

I could go on at length but I think I get the idea across. So the second part of my question is am I right about the connections taking on values in different groups as well?

I can almost taste that theres a very simple way of stating this in the language of fiber bundles, but I'm still learning that formalism.  My first thought though is that we are no longer on the associated tangent bundle, but rather maybe a principle bundle? I honestly don't know. Thank you very much for your time.

Note: I will come back tomorrow and elaborate a bit if no activity (for example the $\mathbb{S}_{\mu\nu}$ basis are $SU(2)$ valued vectors in this example)

Comment: The existence of tetrads is a consequence of the equivalence principle, which is supposed to hold only locally. So it makes sense that you run into trouble, I believe.

Comment: @MannyC Thank you. Yes, in general that is true; however for parallizable manifolds,  one can specify a global tetrad field rather than just some neighborhood of a point. I believe one would say the tangent bundle admits a global cross section. In the standard case I believe it's an so(3,1) (lorentz valued) rotation relating the frames at differing points

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense what you say. But maybe the requirement that the global section must have an $SO(1,3)$ action on it is slightly stronger than parallelizability alone (?)

Comment: @MannyC Thank you again. My understanding is that our only requirement here is that the local section has an SO(3,1) action and one naturally gets this "for free"  at an arbitrary point for any (Lorentzian) pseudoriemannian manifold by virtue of the tangent space at that point being Minkowskian.  
               In that sense, the topological (call it a G) structure for the case above isn't soldered (I think you would say) to the space, but nevertheless is an important part, conveying geometric information. However, I'm new to this, hence me asking